# Grouping into objects using lodash and moment with date as key

Tags: javascript, date, object, momentjs, lodash

I am trying to get some data within an array into objects where the data are grouped according to the month they belong to, so that each will have the month in JavaScript Date object as the key.

```
[
    {
        "date": "2020-08-25T00:00:00.000Z",
        "open": "498.7900",
        "high": "500.7172",
        "low": "492.2100",
        "close": "499.3000",
        "adjusted close": "499.3000",
        "volume": "52873947"
    },
    {
        "date": "2020-08-24T00:00:00.000Z",
        "open": "514.7900",
        "high": "515.1400",
        "low": "495.7450",
        "close": "503.4300",
        "adjusted close": "503.4300",
        "volume": "86484442"
    },
...
    {
        "date": "2020-07-31T00:00:00.000Z",
        "open": "411.5350",
        "high": "425.6600",
        "low": "403.3000",
        "close": "425.0400",
        "adjusted close": "424.2573",
        "volume": "93573867"
    },
    {
        "date": "2020-07-30T00:00:00.000Z",
        "open": "376.7500",
        "high": "385.1900",
        "low": "375.0700",
        "close": "384.7600",
        "adjusted close": "384.0514",
        "volume": "39532505"
    },
...
]
```

Expected Output:

```
{
    "2020-08-01T00:00:00.000Z": {
        "data": [
            {
                "date": "2020-08-25T00:00:00.000Z",
                "open": "498.7900",
                "high": "500.7172",
                "low": "492.2100",
                "close": "499.3000",
                "adjusted close": "499.3000",
                "volume": "52873947"
            },
            {
                "date": "2020-08-24T00:00:00.000Z",
                "open": "514.7900",
                "high": "515.1400",
                "low": "495.7450",
                "close": "503.4300",
                "adjusted close": "503.4300",
                "volume": "86484442"
            },
            ...
        ]
    },
    "2020-07-01T00:00:00.000Z": {
        "data": [
            {
                "date": "2020-07-31T00:00:00.000Z",
                "open": "411.5350",
                "high": "425.6600",
                "low": "403.3000",
                "close": "425.0400",
                "adjusted close": "424.2573",
                "volume": "93573867"
            },
            {
                "date": "2020-07-30T00:00:00.000Z",
                "open": "376.7500",
                "high": "385.1900",
                "low": "375.0700",
                "close": "384.7600",
                "adjusted close": "384.0514",
                "volume": "39532505"
            },
            ...
        ]
    }
}
```

Here is what I have tried so far using lodash and moment, but the date key isn't in the correct format and I had to use the additional variable and for-loop, so I was wondering if there is a better way of achieving this while keeping the date key correct with or without lodash/moment? Would really appreciate if anyone can help me out on this as I am stuck on this for quite some time.

```
  let result = _.chain(arr)
    .groupBy(arr=>
      moment(arr['date'], 'YYYY/MM/DD').startOf(
        'month'
      )
    )
    .value()
  let finalObj = {};
  for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(result)) {
    finalObj[key] = { data: val };
  }
```

Current output - finalObj:

```
{
    "Sat Aug 01 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0800": {
        "data": [
            {
                "date": "2020-08-25T00:00:00.000Z",
                "open": "498.7900",
                "high": "500.7172",
                "low": "492.2100",
                "close": "499.3000",
                "adjusted close": "499.3000",
                "volume": "52873947"
            },
            {
                "date": "2020-08-24T00:00:00.000Z",
                "open": "514.7900",
                "high": "515.1400",
                "low": "495.7450",
                "close": "503.4300",
                "adjusted close": "503.4300",
                "volume": "86484442"
            },
            ...
        ]
    },
    "Wed Jul 01 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0800": {
        "data": [
            {
                "date": "2020-07-31T00:00:00.000Z",
                "open": "411.5350",
                "high": "425.6600",
                "low": "403.3000",
                "close": "425.0400",
                "adjusted close": "424.2573",
                "volume": "93573867"
            },
            {
                "date": "2020-07-30T00:00:00.000Z",
                "open": "376.7500",
                "high": "385.1900",
                "low": "375.0700",
                "close": "384.7600",
                "adjusted close": "384.0514",
                "volume": "39532505"
            },
            ...
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `utc()` and `format()` to fix the month keys, and `mapValues` to perform the final mutation in a lodash-style:

```js
let arr = [{"date": "2020-08-25T00:00:00.000Z","open": "498.7900","high": "500.7172","low": "492.2100","close": "499.3000","adjusted close": "499.3000","volume": "52873947"},{"date": "2020-08-24T00:00:00.000Z","open": "514.7900","high": "515.1400","low": "495.7450","close": "503.4300","adjusted close": "503.4300","volume": "86484442"},{"date": "2020-07-31T00:00:00.000Z","open": "411.5350","high": "425.6600","low": "403.3000","close": "425.0400","adjusted close": "424.2573","volume": "93573867"},{"date": "2020-07-30T00:00:00.000Z","open": "376.7500","high": "385.1900","low": "375.0700","close": "384.7600","adjusted close": "384.0514","volume": "39532505"},];

let result = _.chain(arr)
    .groupBy(arr=>
      moment(arr['date'], 'YYYY/MM/DD').utc().startOf(
        'month'
      ).format()
    )
    .mapValues(data => ({data})) 
    .value();
    
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.16.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```